# Including Windows header conflicts with user defined class names

Tags: c++, windows, qt, include

The following include on a Qt project is conflicting with my user defined classes:

```
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
#include "qt_windows.h"
#include "qwindowdefs_win.h"
#include <shellapi.h>
#endif
```

**Code Snippet:**

```
 if (Desktop::MessageBox::question(this, tr("I am ready?"),
                                     tr("I am not ready yet!?")) == QDialog::Rejected )
            {
                TRACE("Dialog rejected. I am not ready yet.");
                return;
            }
```

**Errors:**
\Desktop\Gui\MainScreen.cpp:953: error: 'Desktop::MessageBoxA' has not been declared

My Desktop::MessageBox is conflicting with windows defined MessageBoxA. What is the standard solution for this problem in c++?

Comment: I must say this is the stupidest "feature" of Windows development. The header files should be smart enough to know that they're being compiled with C++ and use an inline function instead of a macro.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Knowing Microsoft, I believe they have tried this out and have a fairly good estimate how much code would be broken by doing so. E.g. all the codebases that have a `#ifdef MessageBox`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `#undef MessageBox` (and other conflicting names), or
2. Rename your class, or
3. Encapsulate your usage of the Windows API into separate .cpp files so that you don't need to include the Windows headers everywhere, thus (largely) avoiding the problem.

Comment: You forgot option 4: include the Windows includes first, in every single source file, so the name mangling is consistent across your project.

Comment: @MarkRansom:  I thought of that, but the thought was so horrible I could not possibly put it into writing.

Comment: I'm sure it happens by accident more often than you'd care to know.

Comment: The third option is the only safe one IMHO.